# How to slide in image one by one?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to slide three images inside a div one by one but actually on what i'm trying to do the images goes one below other and in the end just stuck in it's oridinal position..

here is the code i'm trying:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="images">
      <img src="images/food.jpg" class="img1"></img>
      <img src="images/food2.jpg" class="img2"></img>
      <img src="images/food3.jpg" class="img3"></img>
  </div>
</div>

.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1080px;
  height: 333px;
}
.images {
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
}

.images img {
  animation: slide-left 0.5s;
  margin-left: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  height: 293px;
}

@keyframes slide-left {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }

}
```

Then i would after some time let the image go out..
Here is how it looks like now i'm posting gyazo link as the gif would be too big for stackoverflow

https://i.gyazo.com/0a17441fd545e58e66e00dd08d8a9c24.gif

While here is an animation i've made with photoshop and i would it looks like it.. (images goes in and after some time goes out)

https://i.gyazo.com/c8e0eed4a53992ce847c9fc372fb748d.gif

Comment: Images also must use the `float` property.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at [Velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/) or [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap/) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using abolute-positioning.

```
.images {
   position: relative;
   width: (your image width);
   height: (your image height);

}

.images img {
  animation: slide-left 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 29px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  top: 0;
  left: -(your image width). <-- negative the width
}

@keyframes slide-left {
  from {
    left: (your negative left value)
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

}
```